# Heroku can't talk to the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have deployed a MERN app to Heroku. The issue is that the backend in my code is http://localhost:5000 and when I try to use the Heroku version, it will try to target the localhost on the computer loading the page and not the server running on Heroku.

How can I solve that? I tried using the Heroku URL but won't solve he issue.

My server file below

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileRoute = require('./routes/file');
require('./db/db');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));

// Serve static assets (build folder) if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.use(fileRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

on the React end I have this var

```
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';
```

FileList.js below and how it calls to backend

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import download from 'downloadjs';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { API_URL } from '../utils/constants';

const FilesList = () => {
  const [filesList, setFilesList] = useState([]);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getFilesList = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/getAllFiles`);
        setErrorMsg('');
        setFilesList(data);
      } catch (error) {
        error.response && setErrorMsg(error.response.data);
      }
    };

    getFilesList();
  }, []);

  const refreshPage = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const downloadFile = async (id, path, mimetype) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/download/${id}`, {
        responseType: 'blob',
      });
      const split = path.split('/');
      const filename = split[split.length - 1];
      setErrorMsg('');
      return download(result.data, filename, mimetype);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
        setErrorMsg('Error while downloading file. Try again later');
      }
    }
  };
  const deleteFile = async (id, path, mimetype) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`${API_URL}/download/${id}`).then(toast.error('Deleted'), refreshPage());
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
        setErrorMsg('Error while downloading file. Try again later');
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="files-container">
      <ToastContainer />

      {errorMsg && <p className="errorMsg">{errorMsg}</p>}
      <table className="files-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Download File</th>
            <th>Delete File</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {filesList.length > 0 ? (
            filesList.map(({ _id, title, description, file_path, file_mimetype }) => (
              <tr key={_id}>
                <td className="file-title">{title}</td>
                <td className="file-description">{description}</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="#/" onClick={() => downloadFile(_id, file_path, file_mimetype)}>
                    Download
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a href="#/" onClick={(notify) => deleteFile(_id, file_path, file_mimetype)}>
                    Delete
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))
          ) : (
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={4} style={{ fontWeight: '300' }}>
                No files found. Please add some.
              </td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilesList;
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you use the Heroku URL in the `API_URL` variable?

Comment: it was a 503 error. But i managed to fix it. I stopped using that API_URL and instead just do "api/downloads" and i had to add a proxy with the backend url to the react package.json file